# Ignorar determinados valores no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(status) FROM $nomeTabela WHERE status=$numeroStatus AND nomePessoa='$nomePessoa'";
```

Tem como otimizar isso? Há status de **0 à 10** (nessa query eu preciso fazer a consulta somente nos status de **1 à 10**), eu queria ignorar os 0 pra consulta ser ainda mais rápida, há mais algumas dicas?

```
foreach ($arrayNomes as $nome) {
    $status1 = retornaStatus(1,$nome,$nomeTabela);
    $status2 = retornaStatus(2,$nome,$nomeTabela);
    $GLOBALS['str'] .=
        "<tr>".
        '<td>'.$nome."</td>".
        '<td>'.$status2."</td>".
        '<td>'.$status1."</td>".
        "<tr>";

}
echo $GLOBALS['str'];
```

Dentro da função tem essa query postado acima de tudo.

Answer (score 1):

User o `NOT` para eliminar valores indesejados

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(status) 
    FROM $nomeTabela 
    WHERE status=$numeroStatus AND nomePessoa='$nomePessoa' AND status NOT IN(0)";
```

Comment: Não tinha pensado nisso, legal!

Answer (score 0):

Você já está filtrando o **status** aqui `status=$numeroStatus` então se você adicionar algum outro operador, exemplo `status=$numeroStatus and status <> 0`, **não** vai ajudar em nada porque ele já está filtrando antes.

Agora se você quer pegar **todos** desde que o status seja **diferente** de `0` ai você não precisa ter o `status=$numeroStatus`. Ficando:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(status) FROM $nomeTabela 
          WHERE status <> 0 AND nomePessoa='$nomePessoa'";
```

Comment: na verdade eu tenho que contar o total de linhas (nome da pessoa e se o status for igual ao nome dela) e jogar em uma tabela, está demorando um pouco, tenho várias tabelas e o número de registros dentro de cada uma varia de (30k a 50k). eu editei lá emcima.

Answer (score 0):

Para otimizar, você pode utilizar PDO e criar métodos para executar sua consulta. Eu não entendi direito, se você quer exibir o total de status, ou se você quer exibir cada um dos status. Mas se for para mostrar o total, segue um exemplo:

```
function query($sql, $params = array(), true)
{ 
  try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seubanco',
        'root', 'senha123');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $result = ($all) ? $stmt->fetchAll() : $stmt->fetch();
        return $result;

  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(); die();
  }

}

function selectTotalStatus($nome, $tabela)
{
$sql = " SELECT COUNT(status) as TOTAL
         FROM :tabela
         WHERE status BETWEEN 1 AND 10
         AND nomePessoa = :nome";

$data_query = array(
              'tabela' =>$tabela,
              'nome'   =>$nome);


$data_result = query($sql, $data_query, $all = true);

$content = [];

    foreach ($data_result as $result) {

       $content[] = "<tr>".
            '<td>'.$result['nomePessoa']."</td>".
            '<td>'.$result['TOTAL']."</td>".
            "<tr>";
 return $content;
}

}
$content = selectTotalStatus('Luiz', 'nome_da_tabela');

echo '<table>'.implode("\n", $content).'</table>';
```